# Twitter API Calls using Parse.com Swift

Tags: swift, twitter, parse-platform

I'm trying to use twitter api calls using parse's sdk with swift language. I was able to get the user's access token, secret and screen name but I'm trying to call https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json and trying return the correct json data but it is always returning **0x0000000000000**

here is the Parse.com Guide which I'm trying to use which is in Objective C https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#twitterusers-requests/iOS and 
Here's my Swift code

```
if PFTwitterUtils.isLinkedWithUser(PFUser.currentUser()) {

    var token : NSString = PFTwitterUtils.twitter().authToken
    var secret : NSString = PFTwitterUtils.twitter().authTokenSecret
    var usern : NSString = PFTwitterUtils.twitter().screenName
    var credential : ACAccountCredential = ACAccountCredential(OAuthToken: token, tokenSecret: secret)

    var verify : NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json")!

    var req:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: verify)
    req.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    PFTwitterUtils.twitter().signRequest(req)
    var response:AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?> = nil
    var error:NSError? = nil

    var data:NSData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(req, returningResponse: response, error: &error)! as NSData

    if error != nil {
        println(error)
    } else {
        println(response)
    }

}
```

I'm not sure where I'm doing this wrong because it is always returning

> 0x0000000000000

Comment: Any luck? I had this prob too.

Comment: no answer yet, tried many other codes but nothing worked, asked on google group still no answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for but from the description it looks like you want the JSON back from Twitter. This should be in your data variable. Anyway here's an answer to everything in case you also want the response back.

```
    //Synchronous version
    if PFTwitterUtils.isLinkedWithUser(PFUser.currentUser()) {

        var token : NSString = PFTwitterUtils.twitter().authToken
        var secret : NSString = PFTwitterUtils.twitter().authTokenSecret
        var usern : NSString = PFTwitterUtils.twitter().screenName

        var credential : ACAccountCredential = ACAccountCredential(OAuthToken: token, tokenSecret: secret)
        var verify : NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json")!
        var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: verify)

        //You don't need this line
        //request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        PFTwitterUtils.twitter().signRequest(request)

        //Using just the standard NSURLResponse.
        var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
        var error: NSError? = nil
        var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request,
            returningResponse: &response, error: nil) as NSData?

        if error != nil {
            println("error \(error)")
            } else {
               //This will print the status code repsonse. Should be 200. 
               //You can just println(response) to see the complete server response
               println((response as NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode)
               //Converting the NSData to JSON
               let json: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,
                options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
               println(json)
            }
        }
```

You can also do this asynchronously. Replace the last section with this and you also don't need the two variables

> error & response

```
    let queue : NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue,
            completionHandler:{(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println("error \(error)")
            } else {
                println((response as NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode)
                let json: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
                    options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
                println(json)
            }

        })
```

Hopefully that answers everything

Answer (score 0):

My app was crashing on the line

```
PFTwitterUtils.twitter().signRequest(req)
```

And the issue was that I was using a user who had recent been logged in with Twitter. Hope this helps.

Comment: @nickchuckwalter My app is also crashing on this line. How were you able to fix this?