# Twitter API sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: arrays, api, twitter, parse-platform, ios9.1

I have an error :"extrat argument error in call" when i remove the error attribute nothing is fixed

```
  let verify = NSURL(string:     "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json")
  var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: verify!)
  PFTwitterUtils.twitter()!.signRequest(request)
  var response: NSURLResponse?
  var error: NSError?
  var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request,  returningResponse: &response, error: &error)
```

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28821847/2428148

Answer (score 0):

```
    if PFTwitterUtils.isLinkedWithUser(PFUser.currentUser()!) {

    let screenName = PFTwitterUtils.twitter()?.screenName!

    PFUser.currentUser()?.username=screenName!
    PFUser.currentUser()?.saveEventually()

 let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=" + screenName!)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        print(data)
        print(response)
        print(error)

    }).resume()
       .....
    }
```